# Force namespaced models form to use root class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

I'm using namespaced models to assign different types of services to a platform :

Relation : `Platform has_many :services` & `Service belongs_to :platform`

Inhéritance : `Service::Service1 < Service`, `Service::Service2 < Service`, etc.

Each service type has a different set of fields (I'm using Mongoid so fields are declared into the model and "submodel" type is stored in a `_type` field).

In `ServicesController::new`, I instanciate new services like this :

```rb
def new
  klass    = "service/#{params[:type]}"
  @service = klass.camelize.constantize.new 
  render :form
end
```

`params[:type]` is given by a route parameter (something like `/:platform_id/services/new/:type`)

In my `form` view, I can now display fields depending on the service type (it's Haml + simple_form) :

```rb
= simple_form_for @service do |f|

[...]

  - case @service.class

  - when Service::Service1
    = f.input :field1

[...]
```

Everything works fine until now : Generated HTML inputs looks like this :

```
<input class="string required" id="service_service1_field1" name="service_service1[field1]" size="50" type="text">
```

With `service_service1[field1]` as field name, my params hash will contain different keys depending on the sub-service and, in my controller's `create` action, I'll have to write a case/when for each sub-service, while `service[field1]` would have "DRYed" my code (I'd just have to add a hidden field with the exact model to instantiate).

Is there a way to force Rails to use the root class as field name when using namespaced models ?

**Edit** : Same question for submit button i18n : Rails looks for `helpers.submit.service_service1.create` where I'd like it to look for `helpers.submit.service.create` as the text is the same for all services.

Comment: `simple_form_for :service` seems to work. I' thought it wasn't possible since root `Service` class has no `Service1` field. I have to make more tests to validate there's no side effect (will the form get fields values on validation errors ?, etc...)

Comment: First side effect: By using a symbol instead of an object, the form builder does not know if it's a create or update action : ID hidden field is not added on edit, I18n looks for `submit` instead of `create` or `update`, validation errors does not feed fields with submitted values, etc. Finally not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `:as` option? I have used this for sub classes but not for name spaces. You may have to do some additional gymnastics with the `:url` option to get your form to post to the correct location.

```
If you have an object that needs to be represented as a different parameter, 
like a Person that acts as a Client:

<%= form_for(@person, :as => :client) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Taken from the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)

Comment: Damn, I spent an hour on the doc without seeing this! (I was looking for something like :model or :class, ...). And now I see there's a big paragraph about `:as`... Thank you very much, it works like a charm !